# Google Maps API custom marker not rendering

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, laravel-blade

So iam using google maps api to make my custom marker, data for multiple marker already created in my controller and exist when i check it via js console

```
<script>
    var markersOnMap = {{ Js::from($marker) }};
</script>
```

[array collection checked][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO2Z5.png

and this is my maps.js class

```
var map;
var InforObj = [];
// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.

// center map
var centerCords = {
    lat: -6.917076,
    lng: 107.618979
};

window.onload = function() {
    initMap();
};

// marker funtion
function addMarker() {
    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
        var contentString = '<div id="content"> <p> <b>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
            '</b> </p></div>' + '<a target="_blank" href="' + markersOnMap[i].url + '">Show Details</a>';

        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
            map: map
        });

        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 200
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            closeOtherInfo();
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            InforObj[0] = infowindow;
        });
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            closeOtherInfo();
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            InforObj[0] = infowindow;
        });


    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js'
    });
}

function closeOtherInfo() {
    if (InforObj.length > 0) {
        /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
        InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
        /* and close it */
        InforObj[0].close();
        /* blank the array */
        InforObj.length = 0;
    }
}

// Add controls to the map, allowing users to hide/show features.
const styleControl = document.getElementById("style-selector-control");



const styles = {
    default: [],
    hide: [{
            featureType: "poi",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
            featureType: "transit",
            elementType: "labels.icon",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
    ],
};


function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: centerCords,
        mapTypeControl: false,
    });

    // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(styleControl);
    map.setOptions({ styles: styles["hide"] });

    document.getElementById("hide-poi").addEventListener("click", () => {
        map.setOptions({ styles: styles["hide"] });
    });

    document.getElementById("show-poi").addEventListener("click", () => {
        map.setOptions({ styles: styles["default"] });
    });

    addMarker();

}
```

but when i check my maps on browser its empty, what should i do ?

Comment: I only skimmed, but did you add the marker to the map itself?

Comment: yes, i add marker base on data from my db, and i create an array inside my controller that match google maps api markerOnMap, then convert it with this: var markersOnMap = {{ Js::from($marker) }};

Comment: Is your ```map``` variable a global variable? If you went by the examples in google maps docs the map variable created only exists within the initialize map function.

Comment: It would be good if you can show your code for initializing the map and also where you call ```addMarker()```.

Comment: updated sir, theres my full code off maps.js file

Answer (score 0):

fixed , i rewrite my maps.js became like this

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.917076, 107.618979),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent('<p>' + locations[i][0] + '</p>' + locations[i][1] + '<br>' + '<a target="_blank" href="' + locations[i][4] + '">Show Details</a>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

const styles = {
    default: [],
    hide: [{
            featureType: "poi",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
            featureType: "transit",
            elementType: "labels.icon",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
    ],
};

map.setOptions({ styles: styles["hide"] });

document.getElementById("hide-poi").addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setOptions({ styles: styles["hide"] });
});

document.getElementById("show-poi").addEventListener("click", () => {
    map.setOptions({ styles: styles["default"] });
});
```